# Tomcat not logging to catalina.out after log rotation using log4j in linux Environment

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have used log4j to rotate catalina.out .After the first log rotation tomcat started logging to newly created file by log4j not to catalina.out in linux environment.Every thing works fine in windows environment.

Here's my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[Java] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %5p - %c{1} : Line No. %L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Is tomcat itself using log4j to log messages?

Comment: @Kenster NO I have so many applications deployed which are writing to catalina.out ( through System.out.Println).

Comment: You need to fix those applications if they are using System.out.println.

Answer (score 3):

The `catalina.out` file is actually created by output redirection from the shell when you launch Tomcat using `bin/catalina.sh` and friends. If you try to rotate that file using log4j, you will clobber that file with your log4j logs. tomcat is still logging to the old catalina.out, which no longer exists.

You should point log4j at a different log file and not rotate catalina.out at all. If you *absolutely must* rotate catalina.out, use another technique.

If your catalina.out is filling up with `System.out.println` garbage from applications, read about the `swallowOutput` option in Tomcat. That will capture `System.out` and `System.err` and redirect it to a file instead of dumping it to standard output.

Comment: thanks for showing interest first.First I cant fix those applications and now tomcat is logging into newly created file by log4j for the first time